# How can I see what line in the less file the compiler cannot recognize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, less

I'm upgrading from Rails 3 to Rails 4 and `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less` is having trouble compiling. Unfortunately only errors I see are with the compiler and not with the file it's trying to process.

For example my error message is:

```
gems/less-2.6.0/lib/less/parser.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in parse': Unrecognised input (Less::Error)
```

and the rest of the stack trace goes on to show me the other `js` and `rb` files from other gems but nothing about the actual source file.

`lessc -h` returns nothing that helps, there isn't a man page on how to see these errors, and combinations of these words aren't helping Google find anything.